# What's wrong with this copy of an xaml+cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've made a copy of an xaml+cs file and I get a lot of errors.. all or most of them have the same message. I've made a printscreen in order to explain the problem better.
I think it's about some elements having the same name and this needs to be changed.. as far as I understand.
Can you help me solve this?

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

EDIT:

xaml code:

```
x:Class="KinectInfoPortal.ImagesGridCopy"
```

cs code:

```
public partial class ImagesGridCopy : Window
```

EDIT2:
cs code:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

xaml code:

```
x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.ImagesGrid"
```

Comment: Also, the containing namespace (full class name) should be same in both xaml and cs. And, the base class in both xaml and cs should be same (`Window` in both or `UserControl` in both).

Comment: Yes, change the second namespace `Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.` to `KinectInfoPortal`

Also, change the ImageGridCopy: Window to ImageGridCopy: UserControl

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to change the name of the class inside the xaml and the cs file. Currently, the both pack of files (xaml+cs) got the same class definition.

So, the members and their events are defined twice.

In order to fix it you have to rename the class inside the copied files.

Xaml:

`<Window x:Class="KinectInfoPortal.ImagesGrid"`

Cs:

`public partial class ImagesGrid : Window`

Comment: and where do I need to write that xaml code? I've tried adding it to references at the beginning, and it didn't work

Comment: It is located at the first line of the xaml file. You should change the ImagesGrid name to another one.

Comment: is this right? look at changes and how many errors I get http://i60.tinypic.com/3518krd.png http://i59.tinypic.com/30k9khy.png

Comment: As I can see, there is another class with the same name. Try changing this name to something else like `ImagesGridCopy`.

Comment: I've tried what you said but unfortunately it didn't do much. See my edited post to see what I've wrote exactly.

Comment: Can you post these two lines of the source file too?

Comment: you mean the code for ImagesGallery, right? i've posted that above

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your copy's class to something else. It's named `ImagesGrid` which already exists in ImagesGrid.xaml / ImagesGrid.cs

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace every occurrence of `ImagesGrid` in the 2 new files with `cat1`, otherwise you got duplicate class names.